# Renaming a NA Named Column Using dplyr or tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a data frame in R where a column name is `NA`. I need to rename this column using `dplyr` or `tidyr` but standard methods aren't working

```
data <- data.frame(a = 1:5)
names(data) = NA
data %>% 
  rename("NA" = NA)
```

How I got NA column name:

```
data %>% 
  count(uncertainty) %>% 
  mutate(freq = round(prop.table(n)*100, 2)) %>%
  data.table::transpose(make.names=1)
```

result :

```
  -1     0     1     2   NA
1  9  6.00 10.00  8.00 3.00
2 25 16.67 27.78 22.22 8.3
```

Comment: How did you create such a data.frame?. Did you import it with a NA column name?  What function did you use to import the data? Is there always only one column in the data.frame? Or what are the other column names?

Comment: `data |> rename("NA" = 1)` would make the first column be named "NA".

Comment: @MrFlick `data.table::transpose(make.names=1)`. No it is not the only column. I want to rename col names dynamically by `rename_with` but i gives error due to column name `NA`

Comment: @JonSpring thank you :). I am seeking a dynamic solution not positional renaming

Comment: It’s probably easiest to avoid getting the NA name in the first place (for instance by replacing NA values before transposing); but you can always use `setNames()` to reassign names, this will work regardless of the previous values.

Answer (score 3):

The best way of handling NA values is usually to replace them with something else *before* they cause issues. In your particular case, replace them after creating the count table, before transposing it:

```
data %>%
  count(uncertainty) %>%
  # Make the value character strings: they will become column names anyway.
  mutate(uncertainty = as.character(uncertainty)) %>%
  replace_na(list(uncertainty = "NA")) %>%
  …
```

This is using `replace_na` from ‘tidyr’. And when using ‘tidyr’, we might as well use `pivot_wider()` instead `data.table::transpose()`:

```
data %>%
  count(uncertainty) %>%
  mutate(uncertainty = as.character(uncertainty)) %>%
  replace_na(list(uncertainty = "NA")) %>%
  mutate(freq = prop.table(n) * 100) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = -n, names_from = 'uncertainty', values_from = 'freq')
```

Or we can skip all the table reformatting rigmarole by directly using `table()`:

```
prop.table(table(data, useNA = 'ifany')) * 100
```

This will return a table. To make it into a data.frame with proper column names we unfortunately need to make it more complicated again:

```
(prop.table(table(data, useNA = 'ifany')) * 100) %>%
  rbind() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(replace_na(names(.), "NA"))
```

Comment: Thank you. `setNames(replace_na(names(.), "NA"))`  is the answer. I consider `uncertainty = as.character(uncertainty)` as an expensive operation, isn't it?

Comment: all I had in my mind the may i need to report bug for `rename` or `rename_with`. What do you think @Konard Rudolph

Comment: @Iman It’s not an expensive operation (why would it be?) and it happens *anyway* implicitly when you use the values as column names, since column names are always strings; so it actually costs nothing here. — I don’t think there’s a bug here: `NA == NA` is `FALSE` by definition, so `rename(x = NA)` is *expected* not to work, and *if* this worked it would require extra handling internally, and arguably violate the user’s expectations, since it breaks the regular NA semantics.

Comment: @Konard Rudolph Complexity of converting the vector to string is  `O(N)`. I think it is better the `rename` somehow handles `NA` colName. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Iman *Any* operation on all elements of a vector is O(N), including `rename()`. Also, O notation isn’t terribly relevant here: these vectors are *tiny*. Big-O is relevant when comparing the growth behaviour of algorithms, and in practice usually only for data sets that are several orders of magnitude larger. And, again, the conversion needs to happen here *anyway*.

Comment: Oh I don't know why I have skipped `count(uncertainty) %>%`   line. ;)

Comment: @Konard Rudolph why not `pivot_wider`? because `data.table::transpose()` gives both `n` and `percent` rows

Comment: @Iman Actually Yes, if you need that, you can add it. But be aware that it’s unusual to have different measures in a given column (such as count and percentage), normally it’s one or the other — except in print table summaries.